# React Native: Performance issue when using `pop()` or `goBack()`, causing an infinite loop. But using `reset` is fine

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I'm experiencing a weird issue in my app, where calling `goBack()` or `pop()` makes the app take all of my RAM and become unusable, and show symptoms of an infinite loop. When I look at RAM (after enabling `show perf monitor`), it shows my RAM being eaten up until the point that the app is unusable.

My screens are like so:

```
    const StacksOverTabs = createStackNavigator(
      {
        Root: {
          screen: TabNav,
          headerMode: 'none',
          navigationOptions: {
            header: null
          }
        },
        ScreenB: {
          screen: ScreenB,
        },
      }
    )
```

I'm going from ScreenA which is inside of `TabNav` into `ScreenB`, by doing `this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB');`, and in `ScreenB` I call `this.props.navigation.goBack()`.

The problem is the same if I use `pop()` instead of `goBack()`, but fixed when I use `StackActions.reset`.

How can I go about debugging what's causing my infinite loop? When I go to ScreenB without `goBack` there are no performance problems.

Comment: Are they just going back and forth from "ScreenB" to "ScreenA" which then calls "ScreenB" again. Maybe make sure "this.props.navigation..." is inside a bound function this.func = this.func.bind(this)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that I have a onEndEditing on a TextInput in ScreenB! For some reason that causes an infinite loop when combined with goBack!